# Data not being inserted on button click

Tags: php

I've got this working normally on page load if I don't try to use a button click. But adding the button click, I'm unable to get the data to insert into my database. Here's the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = "Awesome Name";
    $size = 5.3;
    $color = "black";
    $speciesName = "Tiger";
    $speciesDescription = "Super Test";

    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_type (Name, Description) VALUES ('$speciesName', '$speciesDescription')";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));

    $query = "SELECT Id FROM tbl_type WHERE Name = '$speciesName'";

    if($id = $conn->query($query)){
            $row = $id->fetch_assoc();
            $intId = $row['Id'];
    }

    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_dog (Name, Size, Color, Species) VALUES ('$name', $size, '$color', $intId)";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2) or die("Query fail: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
```

And here's my button:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="btnInsert" type="submit" value="Insert" />
    <input name="btnUpdate" type="button" value="Update" />
</form>
```

I have the feeling I'm missing something silly, I just can't tell what it is. Why will this not insert my data?

Comment: None of your elements have `name="submit"`, therefore there is no `$_POST['submit']`. Try `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: `$_POST['submit']`? where is your input field named `submit`

Comment: See, I knew it was silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Insert" />
    <input name="submit_update" type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

Comment: Or change `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to `if(isset($_POST['btnInsert']))`